# Retrieve Single record on the basis of match Id

Tags: java, collections

I have stored some ids in `Set`,on the basis of which, I want to retrieve single record from the `ArrayList`, I have tried lot of approach, one approach I found, get the index of the matched element and then call `list.get()` method to get the single record.

Whenever I call `indexOf()`, it always return -1, however the element is present in the list

```
public String checkIsHoldingMemberSelected(){
    String result = AppConstants.NO_HOLDING_MEMBER_SELECTED;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    List<Account>selectedMemberList=new ArrayList<Account>();
    try{
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
        if(null != httpSession.getAttribute(AppConstants.SEARCH_HOLDING_MEMBER_IDS)){
            Set<String> smId = (HashSet<String>)httpSession.getAttribute(AppConstants.SEARCH_HOLDING_MEMBER_IDS);
            if(!smId.isEmpty()){
                List<Account>holdingMemberList=(List<Account>) httpSession.getAttribute("memberList");
                for(String memberId:smId) {
                    int index=holdingMemberList.indexOf(memberId);
                    selectedMemberList.add(holdingMemberList.get(index));
                }
                result = AppConstants.SELECTED; 
            }
        }
        json.put("result", result);
        writeJSONData(json);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't have an idea whether this approach is good or not, please suggest me the good approach, my simple requirement is , I have `Set` in which we have memberIds like 1001,1002,1003 ,

now I want to find these ids in the `holdingMemberList`, if there is match then I want that entire record only and add into the other list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem `indexOf` could only works on an entire Account, and then still the objects should be `equals` one to the other. So you have to fetch the member ID from every account.

```
        Set<String> smId =
               (Set<String>) httpSession.getAttribute(AppConstants.SEARCH_HOLDING_MEMBER_IDS);
        if (!smId.isEmpty()) {
            List<Account> holdingMemberList =
                    (List<Account>) httpSession.getAttribute("memberList");
            for (Account account : holdingMemberList) {
                if (smId.contains(account.getMemberId())) {
                    selectedMemberList.add(account);
                }
            }
            result = AppConstants.SELECTED; 
        }
```

The for-loop could also be done with the newer Stream class, for instance like:

```
            List<Account> selected = holdingMemberList.stream()
                    .filter(act -> smId.contains(act.getMemberId())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            selectedMemberList.addAll(selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the proposed approach works, you may end up iterating the `ArrayList` for many times.

A better approach would be that you iterate the `ArrayList` once, and check if `Set.contains()` such Id. If yes, you add it to the result. This way you only iterate the whole `ArrayList` once

```
List<Account> selectedMemberList= new LinkedList<>();
for(Account member: holdingMemberList) {
  if(smId.contains(member) {  //seems like you have overridden the equals() already
    selectedMemberList.add(member);
  }
}
```